# Reject duplicate attribute entry of an array of objects in java swing

Tags: java, netbeans

I try to make a program to register users, so I created an array of users with the attributes: `Usuario` (User ID), `nombre` (name) and `contraseña` (password), and everytime I create a new user the program has to ensure that the User ID hasn't registered before, if it's already registered the program must reject the user register until I put a different UserID, every Object created(every user with it's attributes) is saved in it's respective position of the array, so I create a method with these functions (int `contador` will count the times I register a User, the array has a maximum of 10 so `contador`<10):

```
public  void registrarUsuario(int contador){
         int f = contador;
        usuario = t3.getText();
        nombre = t4.getText();
        contraseña = t5.getText();

            for(int i=0; i<users.length; i++){
\line 43 with error if(users[i].getUsuario() == usuario){
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "El nombre de usuario ya ha sido utilizado");

                }
            }



                
        if(this.t6.getText().equals(this.t5.getText())){  
           Usuario user = new Usuario(usuario, nombre, contraseña);
           users[contador] = user;
            
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "El usuario se ha registrado con exito!");   
        
            this.t3.setText("");
            this.t4.setText("");
            this.t5.setText("");
            this.t6.setText("");
            
        }else{
            
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "ERROR: las contraseñas no coididen");
            this.t5.setText("");
            this.t6.setText("");
            
        }
      
    }
```

but when I run the program I get this error:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at proyecto1.Proyecto1.registrarUsuario(Proyecto1.java:143)
```

( see above to line 143)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got what you're trying to achieve but I didn't fully understand your method because you didn't send all the classes, so i'll send you how i solved it and if you want you can resend us all your classes and code to have a full view :)

My code: (of course you can edit it to be interactive with the user, here i'm showing the general idea only)

```
    //User class
package userArray;

public class User {
    
    private int id;
    private String name;
    private String password;//there is special classes for password in java, not going to use them in this problem

public User(int id, String name, String password) {
        super();
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.password = password;
    }
//getters and setters + toString()

//UsersList class

package userArray;

import java.util.*;

public class UsersList {
    
    ArrayList<User> users = new ArrayList<User>();
    
    //The original function
    public User createUser(int id, String name, String password) throws Exception {
        for(User u : this.users) {
            if(id == u.getId())
                throw new Exception("User already exists...");
        }
        User u = new User(id,name,password);
        this.users.add(u);
        return u;
    }
    
    //The function used to wrap the original function in try/catch each time executed
    public User registerUser(int id, String name, String password) {
           try {
              return createUser(id,name,password);
           } catch (Exception e) {
              System.out.println("ID "+ id +" for user "+name+" is for an existing user...");
              return null;
           }
        }

    public UsersList() {
        super();
        this.users = users;
    }
// + toString()

//Main class

package userArray;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        UsersList list = new UsersList();
        
        list.registerUser(1, "Kevin", "Kevin123");
        list.registerUser(2, "Sarah", "Sarah123");
        list.registerUser(1, "Steven", "Steven123");
        list.registerUser(3, "Stephany", "Stephany123");
        list.registerUser(3, "Alex", "Alex123");
        
        System.out.println("The list is: ");
        System.out.println(list.toString());

    }

}
```

The execution result:

ID 1 for user Steven is for an existing user... 
ID 3 for user Alex is for an existing user... 
The list is: 
UsersList [users=[User [id=1, name=Kevin, password=Kevin123], User [id=2, name=Sarah, password=Sarah123], User [id=3, name=Stephany, password=Stephany123]]]

Answer (score 0):

On this line of code:

```
for(int i=0; i<users.length; i++){
```

You never defined the array **users** - either because you forgot the **this** identifier, or simply forgot to define it.